# Смена цены и кода валюты в зависимости от select

Tags: javascript

Есть код для выбора страны из `select`:

```
function updateContactMethod() {
  var value = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
  if(value == '1') {
    document.getElementById("contact_method").innerHTML = '+375';
  } else {
    document.getElementById("contact_method").innerHTML = '+7';
  }
}
<select id="contactSelect">
    <option value="0">Россия</option>
    <option value="1">Беларусь</option>
</select>
```

Как теперь его доработать, чтобы в строках с `id="cart-price-n"`, при смены страны `<option value="1">Беларусь</option>`, цена умножалась на `0.0322` и `RUB` сменялся на `BYN`, а при выборе `<option value="0">Россия</option>` цена возвращалась по умолчанию?

HTML по умолчанию:

```
<p><span id="cart-price-1" class="cart-price">от 200 RUB набор</span></p>
<p><span id="cart-price-2" class="cart-price">от 400 RUB шт.</span></p>
```

...

```
<p><span id="cart-price-14" class="cart-price">от 2000 RUB/шт.</span></p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Примерно так?

```js
let db = [
  {
    ISO4217: 'RUB',
    multiply: 1
  }, {
    ISO4217: 'UAH',
    multiply: 0.419196405
  }, {
    ISO4217: 'USD',
    multiply: 0.016046
  }
];

document.querySelector('select').addEventListener('change', function (e) {
  let option = db[this.selectedIndex];
  // localStorage['someKey'] = this.selectedIndex;
  
  rebuildPrices(option);
});

/*
let key = localStorage['someKey'];

if(key) {
  document.querySelector('select').selectedIndex = key;
  rebuildPrices(db[key]);
}
*/


function rebuildPrices(option){
  [...document.querySelectorAll('ul span')].forEach(span => span.innerHTML = `${+(+span.parentNode.dataset.cost * option.multiply).toFixed(3)} ${option.ISO4217}`);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li data-cost='1000'>Гвоздь: <span>1000 RUB</span>/1 шт.</li>
  <li data-cost='3500'>Гайка: <span>3500 RUB</span>/1 шт.</li>
  <li data-cost='570'>Шуруповерт: <span>570 RUB</span>/1 шт.</li>
</ul>
<select>
  <option>Россия</option>
  <option>Украина</option>
  <option>США</option>
</select>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/67aqqhu3/

Comment: Спасибо за отличное решение. Как подружить код с `localStorage`? Если до этого на другой странице была выбрана Беларусь, то цена остается по умолчанию в RUB.
`localStorage` сейчас имеет вид: 
`document.getElementById("contactSelect").addEventListener("change", function() {
  localStorage.setItem('contactSelect', document.getElementById("contactSelect").value);
});
if (localStorage.getItem('contactSelect')) {
  document.getElementById("contactSelect").options[localStorage.getItem('contactSelect')].selected = true;
  updateContactMethod.call(document.getElementById("contactSelect"));
}`

Comment: @SvyatoslavVasev, Добавил `localStorage`. В сниппете не работает по соображениям безопасности, но на том же JSFiddle работает.

Comment: Спасибо Вам за помощь. Добавлю что `.toFixed(3)`  регулирует количество цифр после запятой

Answer (score 1):

Лучше всего сделать как показано в ответе @Other: просто добавить `span`'ы для цен, и без проблем заменять их значение.

Но, для полноты картины, все же добавлю (медленный и вероятно ненадежный) вариант, не требующий изменения разметки:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  let cprice, mtchs;
  for (cprice of document.querySelectorAll('.cart-price')) {
    if (mtchs = cprice.textContent.match(/^от (\d+) \w{3}(.*)$/i)) {
      cprice.dataset.priceRur = mtchs[1];
      cprice.dataset.units = mtchs[2];
    }
  }
});

document.getElementById('contactSelect').addEventListener('change', function () {
  let cprice, priceRur, units, priceTxt;
  for (cprice of document.querySelectorAll('.cart-price')) {
    if (!(priceRur = cprice.dataset.priceRur) || !(units = cprice.dataset.units)) {
      console.error('Ошибка изменения текста цены #' + cprice.id);
      continue;
    }
    priceTxt = +this.value ? (+priceRur * 0.0322).toFixed(2) + ' BYN' : priceRur + ' RUB';
    cprice.textContent = `от ${priceTxt}${units}`;
  }
});
```

```html
<select id="contactSelect">
  <option value="0">Россия</option>
  <option value="1">Беларусь</option>
</select>

<p><span id="cart-price-1" class="cart-price">от 200 RUB набор</span></p>
<p><span id="cart-price-2" class="cart-price">от 400 RUB шт.</span></p>
<p><span id="cart-price-14" class="cart-price">от 2000 RUB/шт.</span></p>
<p><span id="cart-price-err" class="cart-price">отъ 42 цѣлковыхъ за одинъ</span></p>
```

Comment: Спасибо за Ваше решение, сделал как показал Other